# Constant holding $this class name

Tags: php, oop

Is there a constant in PHP holding the current sub classes name? So that I can write a function like:

```
namespace test\that;

class MyClass extends ClassA {
}

abstract class ClassA {
    public static function getClassName() {
        return __THIS_CLASS__; // like get_class($this); in a none static method
    }
}
```

In the end I would do something like this:

```
namespace test\other;

use test\that\MyClass;

var_dump(MyClass::getClassName()); // --> test\that\MyClass
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: If in your code the object needs to know its own class name, then you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @tereško I don't think so. You don't know my exact use case so don't judge over it :-).

Comment: I am telling you that it is a *code smell*. And if I would start to guess, then my first hunch would be: your use-case is an active-record ORM.

Comment: @tereško And that's completely wrong :-). Trust me I know what I'm do and I'm also not happy with this solution but it's the best I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking at [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get_called_class); it returns the name of the class the static method is called in.

```
public static function getClassName() {
    return get_called_class();
}

MyClass::getClassName(); // "MyClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `__CLASS__`?

Have a look at the constants:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: If I use `__CLASS__` I get `test\that\ClassA` but I want `test\that\MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's get_called_class() method. To return both parent class and child class names.

[get_called_class()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)